HTTP response when application needs to submit different API request
I am building an app (we'll call it App A) and I have another client app (App B) that needs to send requests to App A via App A's API. The majority of the time, App B is going to send a certain kind of request ("usual request") to App A, but on occasion, App A will respond to this "usual request" and ask App B to send a different kind of request (in a loose sense, it occasionally asks App B to re-authenticate itself). App B will be designed in such a way as to automatically send the "re-authentication" request whenever needed.
What HTTP status code should App A send in response when it wants App B to send the "re-authentication" request? Or should it just be a "Successful" (200-299) response w/ appropriate information in the response body?
Note: I am not asking because I cannot create the desired behavior, I am asking because I want to know what the standard/convention would be in a situation as described.
I have reviewed the status codes in this document and did not come away with a clear answer to my question.

Sounds like a 401 Unauthorized

@Evert App A will throw 401 unauthorized in other situations (e.g. if the API key sent w/ the usual request is invalid). But maybe you are suggesting this should still be 401 unauthorized, just with a different response body?

Sure, but the status applies. OAuth2 will do this for example if the access token needs to be refreshed, which sounds similar to your situation.

That's good to know, and that situation you described with OAuth2 is actually quite similar to what will be happening with these applications. So thanks!
